# Docpad redirects to clean url without cleanurl plugin

Tags: node.js, clean-urls, docpad

When I run `docpad run`, the docpad server redirects links to files with an `.html` extension to the clean urls. At this point, I don't have the cleanurls plugin installed, but I used it earlier in the development process.

E.g. `localhost:9778/de.html` redirects to `localhost:9778/de` which returns "Not Found".

The repo I'm working on is [odl.docpad](http://github.com/fwd-io/odl.docpad).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was having this issue as well. Then I remembered that browsers will cache 301 redirects. Look here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/google-chrome-clear-301-redirect/

Comment: thanks! I updated the answer with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem solved itself. I have absolutely no idea if this was just some random quirk or if I changed something that fixed it. Thanks for the help anyway.

EDIT: 
Apparently the Problem was that browsers cache 301 Redirects (thanks to hypercube for pointing it out). More Information here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/google-chrome-clear-301-redirect/.

Comment: If you ever figure it out, post a comment - want to ensure this quirk never happens for anyone else again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when you were using the cleanurls plugin you did a static environment generate/run? In which case you will have a lot of alias html files placed in your output directory. Running `docpad clean` or `rm -Rf out` then doing another generate/run should fix the issue if this is the case.

Comment: Already did that.. didn't work either. There are no cleanurl "folders" left in the out folder.